# How to delete one row that has a duplicate username to other rows?

Tags: php, sql, delete-row, corresponding-records

This is the table:

```
username:     id:

john          1
john          2
john          56
john          75
john          98
```

Now I want query and delete one of these rows randomly and keep the other four- assuming I do not know the value of "ID" because it was Auto-Incremented.

Here's the code, I'm not sure what to add so it only deletes one of the rows associated with 'john'

```
$query = ("DELETE FROM table WHERE username='$name' && id=''");
```

How do I modify this so it deletes  one row with the name `john` and not all of them?

**Fixed Code**

Simple solution that worked.

```
$query = ("DELETE FROM table WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Sounds like you should probably make `username` a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its possible, but perhaps LIMIT the result to 1?

```
$query = ("DELETE FROM table WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: @user2142549 if an answer works and you think it is good you should click on the check just under the votes. This accepts the answer and gives the answerer reputation. It also gives you 2 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
$name = 'john';

$query = ("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table WHERE username = '$name' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)");
```